# React Native Networking with react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch

Hey guys I have a short question. I want to give every Button a other Page.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.movies });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

The Code give me the movie names as Button and I can click on everyone. Right now I want to open for every Button a other page with react-native-router-flux.

```js
{
"title": "The Basics - Networking",
"description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
"movies": [
{
"id": "1",
"title": "Star Wars",
"releaseYear": "1977"
},
{
"id": "2",
"title": "Back to the Future",
"releaseYear": "1985"
},
{
"id": "3",
"title": "The Matrix",
"releaseYear": "1999"
},
{
"id": "4",
"title": "Inception",
"releaseYear": "2010"
},
{
"id": "5",
"title": "Interstellar",
"releaseYear": "2014"
}
]
}
```

This is the Json Data where I fetch the names. Maybe the "id" will help me, but I really dont know what can I right now do.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you some recommend, because it is too rough to explain although is is a short question.

I remember using `react-native-router-flux` have to import your scene(page) and using `Actions.somepage()` to route to the page. But using `FlastList` is hard to `Actions.eachpage` like this. (Maybe just my skills are not good enough to achieve)

If you want to achieve like your description, I will recommend you to create a new page component to handle all of the scene now we just called "HandlePage", and then you could add it to your `TouchableOpacity` by using like

```js
import HandlePage from "./HandlePage";
...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { Actions.HandlePage({page: item.id}); }}
```

So that you could control the page at `HandlePage` , take this parameter(id) to handle which page you want to render. Actually, is only using one `Actions.HandlePage` to route but have more flexible to render what you want.

Hope it could help.

---

**Update:**

Something like:

```js
import StarWars from "./StarWars";
import TheMatrix from "./TheMatrix";
import Inception from "./Inception";
import Interstellar from "./Interstellar";

export default class HandlePage extends React.Component {
  checkSwitch = param => {
    switch (param) {
      case "1":
        return <StarWars/> ;
      case "2":
        return <TheMatrix recordCount = {this.state.recordCount}/>;

      case "3":
        return <Inception disabled = {this.state.disabled3}/>;

      case "4":
        return <Interstellar alert = {this.state.alert4}/>;

      default:
        return null;
    }
  };
  render() {
    return ({
      this.checkSwitch(this.props.page)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you show me how do you think will the handlePage.js will look like?

Comment: I get a error. When I click the button there stands: TypeError: _reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.HandlePage is not a function.

It can not take the import HandlePage inside the button :/

Comment: have you import the "Actions"?

Comment: And you need to use like arrow function `() => { Actions.HandlePage({page: item.id}); }`